# Неточный поиск по символам

Tags: алгоритм, php, строки

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться с алгоритмом: дано 2 строки которые нужно сравнивать, и если найдено совпадение хотя бы в 3 последовательных символах то выводить сообщение. Как я думаю сначала нужно как то разбить строку на группы символов (с этим проблема) чтобы были все возможные варианты, т.е. если строка `test` то группы выходят `tes`, `est`. Потом циклом `foreaech` пройтись по массиву с группами и в условии искать совпадение во 2 строке при помощи `strpos()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот как-то так, хотя наверное можно изящнее:
(резать можно на лету)

```
$str1 = 'строка1'
$str2 = 'строка2'
$iLen = strlen($str1);
for($i = 0; $i<$iLen-3; $i++) {
    if (strpos($str2, substr($str1, $i, 3)) !== false) {
        echo 'совпадение найдено';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> сначала нужно как то разбить строку на
> группы символов (с этим проблема)

Решение "в лоб":

```
$s = '12345678';
// тут проверить, что в строке не меньше 3 символов!
$max = strlen($s) - 2;
$tokens = array();

for( $i = 0; $i < $max; $i++ )
{
    $tokens[] = substr($s, $i, 3);
}

print_r( $tokens );

Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 234
    [2] => 345
    [3] => 456
    [4] => 567
    [5] => 678
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант функции для определения наличия совпадения:

```
function cmp3($s1, $s2) {
    // Для уменьшение кол-ва проходов определим меньшую строку
    $s2 = [$s2, $s1];
    $s1 = array_splice($s2, mb_strlen($s1) < mb_strlen(reset($s2)), 1)[0];
    $s2 = reset($s2);

    for ($i = 0, $l = mb_strlen($s1) - 2; $i < $l; ++$i) {
        if (mb_strpos($s2, mb_substr($s1, $i, 3)) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```